# TTLauncher in Xcode 4.0

Tags: iphone, xcode, three20, ttlauncherview

Is there anybody who has successfully used Three20 v1.1 in Xcode 4?
I have a project with `TTLauncher`, but cannot get it to work properly (Creating an Archive for distribution). The v1.1 branch hasn't been merged yet with the updated 1.0.5 it seems.

Also, I don't seem to be able to run it anymore in the simulator, although it is ok on the iPhone.There seems to be a problem here in `TTURLNavigatorPattern`:

> NSInvalidArgumentException: -[TTURLNavigatorPattern setSelectorWithNames:]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x5c14f80

Originating in:

> [map from:@"tt://ArticleTableView/(initWithCategory:)"toViewController:[ArticleTableViewController class]];

Comment: One of the problems for building the 'Archieve' is: ../scripts/Protect.command: line 23: cd: /Users/[...]/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/../three20/Three20Core: No such file or directory.
There should be another '../' in there, i.e. Release-iphoneos/../../three20/Three20Core.

I don't know enough about the build process to know how to fix this. Is it easy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With my multiple tries to get the V1.1 to work I must have broken something in Xcode 4, so I ended up re-creating the whole project and just putting all my code back in (which allowed me to re-organsie it and put it into a new repo as well). Now using the 1.0.5 version of Three20 (and just wrote a TTNavigationController myself which does the simple job I am looking for now) it all seems to work again on both the iPhone as in the simulator.